# Reading UTF-8 file returns unexpected chars

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

Running Windows 8 64-bit. I have a file where I store some data, saved with the UTF-8 encoding using Windows notepad. Supposing this is the content of the file:

> 1,some,data,here,0,-1

I'm reading it like this:

```
f = open("file.txt", "rb")
f.read()
f.close()
```

And `f.read()` returns this:

> u"\xef\xbb\xbf1,some,data,here,0,-1"

I can just use `f.read()[3:]` but that's not a clean solution.

What are those characters at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Sorry, I was mixing python2 features set with that of other languages and python3... In python2 unicode text handling is far from being perfect... Simply skipping the first 3 bytes and optionally (if you need unicode objects) using s[3:].decode('utf-8') when the utf-8 bom is present is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I really want to migrate to Python 3, I'm tired about all this encoding stuff and those `UnicodeDecodeError`s. The problem is that the hosting doesn't have Python 3 (and they won't install it) so I need to do it like this.

Comment: Sure, most paranoid debians/old distros still have only python2 by default and unfortunately unicode is just a hack in python2 and the api only partly supports unicode objects. For example the subprocess module simply throws an exception if you use unicode strings, it still accepts only ansi - I've had hard time with this not too long ago. I'm also still using a fair amount of python2 but I see that switching to full python3 is near. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those first 3 bytes are the UTF-8 BOM, or Byte Order Mark. UTF-8 doesn't **need** the BOM (it has a fixed byte order unlike UTF-16 and UTF-32), but many tools (mostly Microsoft's) add it anyway to aid in file-encoding detection.

You can test for it and skip it safely, use [`codecs.BOM_UTF8`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.BOM_UTF8) to handle it:

```
import codecs

data = f.read()
if data.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8):
    data = data[3:]
```

You could also use the [`io.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) function to open the file and have Python decode the file for you to Unicode, and tell it to use the `utf_8_sig` codec:

```
import io

with io.open('file.txt', encoding='utf_8_sig'):
    data = f.read()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the first code. I'll mark this as my accepted answer because of the code examples, but thanks to those who answered too!

Comment: +1, I didn't know about this io module solution, its a pity that there is no auto-detect solution in either codecs or io...

Comment: @pasztorpisti: encoding autodetection is at best a fuzzy affair. Even  with a BOM you cannot be certain about the codec used.

Answer (score 1):

That´s the BOM (byte order mark).
In reality, UTF-8 has only one valid byte order,
but despite of that there can be this 3-byte-sequence
at the beginning of the file (data in general).

-> If there are exactly these values as first 3 bytes, ignore them.